# C library for linear algebra

Tags: c, linear-algebra

Please, give me some tips for a HIGH PERFORMANCE C library for linear algebra (matrix algebra, eigenvalues, eigenvectors etc.). Can be both open-source or closed-source.

Comment: Who ever makes the effort to write a library like that and make it low perf?  Shopping questions are off topic at SE.

Comment: GSL did. They made a very portable and wide functionality library, but they did not optimize it well both in multiplatform way and in platform-depended way.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. [CLAPACK (f2c'ed version of LAPACK)](http://www.netlib.org/clapack/)
2. [GSL - GNU Scientific Library](http://www.gnu.org/s/gsl/)

**EDIT** Thanks to comments from osgx:

- CLAPACK is the library which uder the hood uses very high-performance BLAS library, as do other libraries, like ATLAS.
- GSL is a standalone C library, not as fast as any based on BLAS. However its performance is still quite good (not *extremely* good though) and is used quite often; mostly because of its portability.

I know both LAPACK and GSL and I can recommend both of them. LAPACK is very low-level library and GSL may be more comfortable to use, but speaking of good performance -- BLAS-based library it is.

Comment: Of course, as well as decompositions, etc. See: http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lawn41/node111.html (and the rest of the documentation).

Comment: Which is better/faster for SVD and eigenvectors?

Comment: Good BLAS library (basic matrix-matrix; vector-matrix; vector-vector operations), e.g. ATLAS or GotoBLAS or Intel MKL + some LAPACK, which uses BLAS (all BLAS libraries have the same interface). The GSL  will not use the high-performance BLAS.

Comment: Actually LAPACK is based mostly on BLAS (level 3). I didn't use ATLAS, but as far as I know its performance is comparable to LAPACK.

Comment: So we have an agreement: any library based on BLAS is good for high-performance computing. GSL is higher-level standalone library, but still relevant for many cases (not all though).

Comment: Sorry, actually, gsl may link with external BLAS library (cblas function names).

Comment: And basing of LAPACK on BLAS is the reason why LAPACK need little tuning of code to perform very good. All tuning is done in Good BLAS Library; autotuning in Atlas; handwriting of 100s kilobyte of asm in GotoBLAS; pirating GotoBLAS asm in MKL. Some tuning also was in AMD's ACML. But the GSL's internal BLAS is not tuned.

Answer (score 5):

[ATLAS](http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/), maybe?

Edit: if you're open to C++, you should definitely check [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page), it's a very neat library, and pretty fast too, according to the benchmarks.

Answer (score 0):

Again if you are actually looking/open for modern C++ code, [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/) is getting really hyped/popular.
Also see their own [benchmarking](http://arma.sourceforge.net/speed.html) against **IT++** and **Newmat**.