# Any way to vectorize in C

Tags: c

My question may seem primitive or dumb because, I've just switched to C.
I have been working with MATLAB for several years and I've learned that any computation should be vectorized in MATLAB and I should avoid any `for` loop to get an acceptable performance.
It seems that if I want to add two vectors, or multiply matrices, or do any other matrix computation, I should use a `for` loop.
It is appreciated if you let me know whether or not there is any way to do the computations in a vectorized sense, e.g. reading all elements of a vector using only one command and adding those elements to another vector using one command.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks you all. I really appreciate your help. It was a lot helpful.

Answer (score 3):

MATLAB suggests you to avoid any `for` loop because most of the operations available on vectors and matrices are already implements in its API and ready to be used. They are probably optimized and they work directly on underlying data instead that working at MATLAB language level, a sort of opaque implementation I guess.

Even MATLAB uses for loops underneath to implement most of its magic (or delegates them to highly specialized assembly instructions or through CUDA to the GPU).

What you are asking is not directly possible, you will need to use loops to work on vectors and matrices, actually you would search for a [library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228575/c-library-for-linear-algebra) which allows you to do most of the work without directly using a for loop but by using functions already defined that wraps them.

Answer (score 2):

As it was mentioned, it is not possible to hide the for loops. However, I doubt that the code MATLAB produces is in any way faster the the one produced by C. If you compile your C code with the `-O3` it will try to use every hardware feature your computer has available, such as SIMD extensions and multiple issue. Moreover, if your code is good and it doesn't cause too many pipeline stalls and you use the cache, it will be really fast. 
But i think what you are looking for are some libraries, search google for LAPACK or BLAS, they might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In C there is no way to perform operations in a vectorized way. You can use structures and functions to abstract away the details of operations but in the end you will always be using fors to process your data.

As for speed C is a compiled language and you will not get a performance hit from using for loops in C. C has the benefit (compared to MATLAB) that it does not hide anything from you, so you can always see where your time is being used. On the downside you will notice that things that MATLAB makes trivial (svd,cholesky,inv,cond,imread,etc) are challenging in C.

Comment: In fact good compilers can take advantage of the SIMD units present on CPUs. Gcc does that when you turn on more than the lowest level of optimization.