# Using Eigen with C

Tags: c, codeblocks, eigen

I want to use Eigen with C. I read this other post ([Using Eigen in a C Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26889142/using-eigen-in-a-c-project)) and essentially copied it in Code Blocks 17.12. When I try to compile, a red square warning appears in the row where `#include "foo.h"` appears for the first time and I am getting an error saying "foo.h: no such file or directory". Has this something to do with the "**building**" paragraph of the aforementioned post where it says "Use a C++ compiler to build the shared library libfoo.so. Use a C compiler to build the main program, linking to the shared library. The exact build steps may vary for your compiler/platform." If yes, how am I supposed to do this, if not what do I have to do?

Comment: Did you create the `foo.h` header as shown in the linked answer? Is it in the correct path?

Comment: I literraly copied and pasted the blocks of code so I guess yes, it is the same as the linked answer. How can I check the path though?